# Subclass of UIButton with custom layer doesn't fill space to adjacent view completely

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I was trying to create a square button with an icon, where the background is transparent. When the button gets highlighted the background turns white. Everything worked, but then I noticed that the right white border of the button when highlighted wasn't as sharp as the rest of the border. After some research I realized that this only happens if the view to the right is set to "Align Center X to: Superview". Here is an example I made:

[image]

The white field you see is the rectangular button I made (code below). Notice that there is some red background color visible through the small gap between the button and the green UIView. The green view is set to "Align Center X to: Superview", and the button has Trailing space 0 to the green view. The blue UIView under does not experience this strange gap.

Now look at this picture:

[image]

This is the exact same setup, but now the green UIView has "Trailing Space to: Superview = 140" instead of X-centering. Now the gap is gone! Why can this be?

Here is the code for drawing the white button.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SquareButton: UIButton {

var iconLayer: CAShapeLayer!

func setup() {
    if iconLayer == nil {
        iconLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        // Create a custom white background color
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        // Set forState .Normal just for this example
        self.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    }
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by instead of setting a white background image, I created a filled CAShapeLayer and added it as a sublayer to the button. That worked for some reason.